# Is AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.quality broken?

Tags: macos, avfoundation, macos-monterey, avspeechsynthesizer

The `quality` property appears to be undefined on all of the provided voices (`AVSpeechSynthesisVoice`). The enum has only two cases, `default`, and `enhanced`, which have raw values 1 and 2. I notice some voices are much better than others, and I was hoping I could use this property to programmatically find the better ones. But...

```swift
extension AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceQuality: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .default: return "default"
        case .enhanced: return "enhanced"
        default: return "??? (rawValue=\(rawValue))"
        }
    }
}

print(AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceQuality.default)
print(AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceQuality.enhanced)
let all = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
print("\(all.count) voices")
for voice in all {
    print("\(voice.language) -> \(voice.quality)")
}
```

Output look like:

```
default
enhanced
52 voices
en-US -> ??? (rawValue=0)
it-IT -> ??? (rawValue=0)
sv-SE -> ??? (rawValue=0)
fr-CA -> ??? (rawValue=0)
es-MX -> ??? (rawValue=0)
...
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Bump - any insights to share?

Comment: Not yet, but maybe in a few weeks. I'm just getting back to this code.